# How to execute a gradle task after android dexDebug or dexRelease task

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I want to run a Gradle task to execute some shell scripts after dexRelease or dexDebug task during the android build.

I have tried the below approach

```
task taskAfterDex(type:Exec) {

    workingDir '.'
    executable 'sh'
    args "-c", "source scriptskAfterDex.sh"
    ignoreExitValue true
    doLast {
        println "taskAfterDex completed"
    }
}


tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'dexRelease') {
        task.dependsOn taskAfterDex
    }
}
```

but am not getting the execution phase log or it's not executing after dexRelease/Debug.

```
>  Gradle 4.8
> 
> 
> Build time:   2018-06-04 10:39:58 UTC Revision:    
> 9e1261240e412cbf61a5e3a5ab734f232b2f887d
> 
> Groovy:       2.4.12 Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11
> compiled on March 23 2018 JVM:          1.8.0_151 (Oracle Corporation
> 25.151-b12) OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.2 x86_64
>
```

Comment: How do you execute the _Gradle_ run?

Comment: @tynn , Using android studio -> Generate signed apk option.

Comment: The way you defined this is that `dexRelease` depends on `taskAfterDex`. That means that `taskAfterDex` will be run *before* `dexRelease` task and not after.

Comment: @Blaz

i have updated , but am not getting the execution phase log  


   doLast {
        println "taskAfterDex completed"
    }


How can i make sure that , my custom task is executing after dexRelease/debug

Comment: Does `dexRelease` even run? Did the sample run on my end and that tasks are never executed. Not sure when that task is meant to be run. Alternatively, you could try to use `register` or method on a variant, depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @Blaz If we print task.name within tasks.whenTaskAdded block

we can see the dexRelease/DexDebug  (based on the build type debug/release)


i want to run my task immediately after the dex files got generated, and before generating APK

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is a [finalizer task](https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.2/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#finalizedBy-java.lang.Object...-). Also, `whenTaskAdded` doesn’t work for tasks that have already been added before; using `all` may be safer:

```
tasks.all { task ->
    if (task.name == 'dexRelease') {
        task.finalizedBy 'taskAfterDex'
    }
}
```

As @Blaz has noted in the question comments, your approach with `dependsOn` does the opposite: it adds `taskAfterDex` as a dependency of `dexRelease`, i.e., `taskAfterDex` is run *before* `dexRelease`.

Comment: I have  tried this,
But the order of execution is just based on the position in the gradle file ,

if I put tasks.all {} and prints somthing  before 'whenTaskAdded'  section  its printing  b fbefore , else after  'whenTaskAdded'


and 


if i print somthing in the task like this



task mobilityTask  {

   println "--------> mobilityTask"

    doLast {
      println "...to an end."
   }

}


doLast section is not executing.. means log inside doLast is not printing ...

if i add anything outside the DoLast its executing even before tasks.all OR whenTaskAdded

Comment: > Configure project :xxxxx
---------> inside taskAfterDex config
---------> last line  in taskAfterDex config
--------- tasks.all dexDebug
--------- whenTaskAdded dexDebug


----- 
this is how it's printing in the Build console

and if i add my shell scripts outside the doLast of the 'taskAfterDex' task then it's executing even before.

Comment: Are you aware of the [build phases](https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.2/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) of Gradle? It’s especially important to understand the difference between the _configuration phase_ and the _execution phase_: depending on where you add your `println` statements, they will be run in different build phases. When you see build log output under `> Configure project :xxxxx`, then that comes from the configuration phase. When you see logs under something like `> Task :foo`, then that comes from the execution phase.

Comment: It’s hard to tell from your comments what’s going on for you. Could you maybe rather add more details to your question (as there is more room there and more formatting allowed)? If that’d help, I could also provide a self-contained example that shows that my proposed answer should work; just let me know.

Comment: am aware of build phases,
i have added logs in both config phase and execution phase, but am not getting any logs from execution phase, 

if i print the task names I can see the dexDebug/dexRelease during config phase  but none of them appearing in the execution phase 

>Task :xxxxx

Comment: So maybe the `dexDebug`/`dexRelease` tasks are simply not executed then … why do you believe they should be? Do you see the task names printed when using the `--console=verbose` Gradle option?

Comment: Task name is not printing under execution phase, its showing only during config phase,

Comment: Are the tasks you’re looking for maybe rather called `mergeDexDebug`/`mergeDexRelease`? At least those tasks produce the `classes.dex` files that you have mentioned in [your related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60755870/1797912) for a tiny Android test project build for me. Also, have you added the `tasks.all { … }` code to `./app/build.gradle` (which would be the right location, I suppose, rather than `./build.gradle`)?